# "unable to open '/usr/share/icons/Pop/16x16@2x/actions/bookmark-new.png.dpkg-new': No such file or directory" error while trying to update

Tags: package-management, updates, 20.04

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease    
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [106 kB]    
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release    
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease    
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]    
Fetched 213 kB in 4s (48.5 kB/s)       
Reading package lists... Done    
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done    
Calculating upgrade... Done    
The following packages will be upgraded:    
  pop-icon-theme    
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.    
Need to get 0 B/7,360 kB of archives.    
After this operation, 46.0 MB disk space will be freed.    
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y    
(Reading database ... 326295 files and directories currently installed.)    
Preparing to unpack .../pop-icon-theme_2.1.0~1583343731~20.04~11f18cb~ubuntu1_all.deb ...   
Unpacking pop-icon-theme (2.1.0~1583343731~20.04~11f18cb~ubuntu1) over 
(1.4.0~1565992228~18.04~2bac292) ...   
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-icon-
theme_2.1.0~1583343731~20.04~11f18cb~ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):   
 unable to open '/usr/share/icons/Pop/16x16@2x/actions/bookmark-new.png.dpkg-new': No such file or directory   
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-icon-theme_2.1.0~1583343731~20.04~11f18cb~ubuntu1_all.deb   
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `apt-cache policy pop-icon-theme`:

```
pop-icon-theme:
  Installed: 1.4.0~1565992228~18.04~2bac292
  Candidate: 2.1.0~1583343731~20.04~11f18cb~ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.1.0~1583343731~20.04~11f18cb~ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
 *** 1.4.0~1565992228~18.04~2bac292 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. I removed the package and reinstalled using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge pop-icon-theme
sudo apt install --reinstall pop-icon-theme
```